# 'npm install' throws error on remote host 'cannot read property 'length' of undefined'

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5, npm

I am trying to deploy my local development to GitHub and also let my Webserver pull from Github (which works fine).

I clone my Laravel Repository from Github to my Server. After that I run composer install (which works fine).
But when running npm install I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /.npm/_logs/2017-11-12T14_48_59_351Z-debug.log
```

I checked the log file: it is empty.

Further, running other commands like `npm help config` throws this error:

```
npm ERR! file man
npm ERR! path man
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn man
npm ERR! enoent spawn man ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent Check if the file 'man' is present.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /.npm/_logs/2017-11-12T14_49_57_777Z-debug.log
```

I just installed node and npm on my shared hosting via the command line. 
`npm -v` results in `5.5.1`

Any ideas how to solve this? Could this be an error within NPM?

**EDIT**

I tried several other node & npm versions and with  node.js v7.10.1 and npm 4.2.0 at least `npm install` starts running. It then produces the following error (which brings me to the conclusion that I need a newser version of npm, but the newer versions throw the errors mentioned above):

```
└── vuejs-datepicker@0.9.19 

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0             (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for     fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:     {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-98-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/node-v7.10.1-linux-x64/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! mozjpeg@4.1.1 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mozjpeg@4.1.1 postinstall script 'node lib/install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mozjpeg package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node lib/install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs mozjpeg
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mozjpeg
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /.npm/_logs/2017-11-12T15_23_08_709Z-debug.log
```

Any way I could come around this issue without installing a new npm version? That might help me, too. I am very grateful for any help. 
Thank you!

Comment: There are a number of issues open on the mozjpeg package pertaining to installation problems:  https://github.com/imagemin/mozjpeg-bin/issues

Comment: I don't even know if the package is required. Since the error occured in the tree right after vuejs-datepicker, does that mean the datepicker requires mozjpeg? Is there any way I can do the installation without mozjpeg?

Comment: can you post your actual dependencies?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EWYXtCJz